# Set atomic vector names by reference

Tags: r, data.table, pass-by-reference

I am wondering if it is possible to set vector names by reference in R.

I often use `data.table::fread` to read text files, and then I clean up the variable names by wrapping `setnames` (which also works on a plain `data.frame`) and a string cleanup function similar to:

```
clean_var_name <- function(s) {
  gsub("^_+|_+$","",gsub("(\\s|\\-|[[:punct:]])+", "_", tolower(s) ) )
}
```

so my function looks like:

```
clean_names <- function(x){
  require(data.table)
  if(is.data.frame(x)){setnames(x, names(x), clean_var_name(names(x)))} # this part works
  else if(is.vector(x)){ do_something_here } # this is the question
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to include the case of vectors in the same function in a way that performs  `names(x) <- clean_var_name(names(x))` by reference.

```
v <- c(`thIs.Is.A.Terrible-Name`=1, `this One is TOO`=2)
dt <- data.table(t(v))
clean_names(dt)
dt 
#    this_is_a_terrible_name this_one_is_too
# 1:                       1               4    
# would like to be able to do same for clean_names(v)
```

I'm also open to explanations of why this is a bad idea (side effects, functional programming, etc.)

Comment: Fyi, you don't need all three args of `setnames`. `setnames(x,names(x),y)` is just `setnames(x,y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setattr` function:

```
library(data.table)
x <- 1:10
address(x)
# [1] "0x713cfd0"
setattr(x,"names",letters[1:10])
address(x)
# [1] "0x713cfd0"
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed this, since `?setnames` points right to it.  Thanks.  To be thorough, here is the solution: `clean_names <- function(x){ require(data.table); setattr(x, "names", clean_var_name(names(x)) ) }`.  Note that this works for atomic vectors and data.frames alike, so we can get rid of the `if...setnames` to simplify.